# Different duration from Eloquent query and phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an app in Laravel 5.5.
I have installed this library for see query on my app: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

And now, in my app, with library, I can see that I make a big query like:

> select `values`.*, `user_value`.`user_id` as
>   `pivot_user_id`, `user_value`.`value_id` as
>   `pivot_value_id` from `values` inner join `user_value` on
>   `values`.`id` = `user_value`.`value_id` where
>   `user_value`.`user_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
>   '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
>   '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', [....]) and
>   `values`.`deleted_at` is null

where [...] are other 4 thousands id to find.

The stranger thing is that if I copy and paste the query in my Phpmyadmin, the query take  0.0492 seconds, but in debug console I see that query take 3.86 seconds.
So there is a difference from duration, and I don't understand why.
What could be a problem?

My app query made with eloquent is:

```
$users= User::with('values')->find($request->input('users'));
```

where `$request->input('users')` is ids Array.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problems might come from the binding laravel is doing, because in the debugbar, it seems that's it's the same request, but it's not, one is using bindings while the other is not.

I have an opened issue on the laravel framework here : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26051

so for some case you might want to do the following :

```
  $users = User::find($request->input('users'));
  $values_per_user = Value::whereRaw("id in ('" . implode("','", $users->pluck('id')->toArray()) . "')")->get()->groupBy('user_id');
```

and after where you are in the context of your user, you can do :

`$values = $values_per_user[$user->id]`

Not applicable everywhere (like if you are using your relation in custom getter or function) but it can works for simple needs